# which one is integrable acoording to f & g

Tags: measure-theory

Let f, g : R $\to$ R be integrable functions. Show which of the following
functions are necessarily integrable:

a)$f^2$      b)$f^{1/3}$     c)$f(x)\sin(x)$ 
   d)$\arctan(f)$      e)$\sqrt{\mid f\mid}$ 
    f)$\sqrt{\mid fg \mid}$       g) (f/1 + $\mid g \mid)$.

answer:I think that without part d the rest are integrable according to dominated convergence theorem because  f is integrable so  $\int(f)$<$\infty$ and from this we can conclude that alle function above  without part d are smaller than f so they are integrable,Is that true?

Comment: I hope you are aware of Hölder's inequality and the estimate $|\arctan(a)|\leq|a|$. Your guess of the integrable ones is wrong, but I don't want to spoil it for you.

Comment: could you plz more explain it voor me?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(a) Let $f(x)=x^\alpha$ when $x\in(0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. What happens with different exponents $\alpha$?

(b) Let $f(x)=x^\beta$ when $x>1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. What happens with different exponents $\beta$?

(c) Use the fact that $|f(x)\sin(x)|\leq|f(x)|$.

(d) Use the fact that $|\arctan(f(x))|\leq|f(x)|$.

(e) Similar to (b).

(f) What happens if you use Hölder's inequality for the functions $\sqrt{|f|}$ and $\sqrt{|g|}$?

(g) If you meant f/1+|g|, use the triangle inequality pointwise. If you meant something else, please clarify.

Comment: thank you,but for part a) and b) Ido not still understand wat you mean these{ function part a) and part b) } goes to zero for diff exponent of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but what does this have to do with integrability of $f^2$ and $f^(1/3)$?

Comment: @moj: In part (a), for which values of $\alpha$ is $f$ integrable? For which values of $\alpha$ is $f^2$ integrable? This will help answering your question. You can use a similar method for part (b).